# I can't find grant information of my oracle view

Tags: oracle

I have 2 oracle accounts A & B.
View V owned by B can be selected by A, but I can't find any grant information in DBA_TAB_PRIVS for V.
Is this possible? What am I missing?

**Update**

I actually have a role (let's call it roleAB) which set to user A & B. Generally I grant A's view to roleAB so that B can select and vice versa.

I did grant and revoke again, I can saw records in DBA_TAB_PRIVS appear and gone, and the view can be selected by opposite user (after grant) and insufficient privileges (after revoke) correctly now. Don't know what happened yesterday...=(

But, another weird thing happen: I do the same thing to a table, when I revoke the privilege, it shows "table or view does not exist" but not "insufficient privileges" and I am pretty show the table is there. My Oracle is 11g.

Comment: Does User A have the "SELECT ANY TABLE" privilege? Are any select privileges on V assigned to a *role* that is also assigned to User A?

Comment: This Pete Finnigan script will tell you all privileges a user has, and their source (direct grant vs role).  I use it quite frequently for this type of question:  http://www.petefinnigan.com/find_all_privs.sql

Comment: If it's "your" view, did you run any GRANT statements?

Comment: @pmdba I checked and A only have UNLIMITED TABLESPACE, CREATE SYNONYM, CREATE ANY VIEW, CREATE TABLE, CREATE SESSION in  DBA_SYS_PRIVS.

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica I think any grant statement will be recorded in DBA_TAB_PRIVS but there is nothing. That's why I have this question.

Comment: @EdStevens I run the script but encounter ORU-10027: buffer overflow, limit of 1000000 bytes no matter I choose screen or file output. The user A may has too many privileges. Don't know what to do now...

Comment: @Magic - regarding the buffer overflow, I don't know. I'd ask the script's author, Pete Finnigan.  I know from experience that he is quite accessible.  Just poke around on his site for contact or feedback links.